# How do I change source url of an image which has been dynamically added to a div?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div in which I am dynamically adding an image.

```
div.append('<img class="prod48" src="' + url + '" />');
```

Now the `url` is set by `focusout` of a textbox depending on the text in it. Since the append function will go on appending, how should I just change this `url` and not append another image in the `div`? The first time the `focusout` is called only then should I be able to append and rest times updating the url.

Comment: by url do you mean the src ?

Comment: yes. I am setting as src = 'url'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to update the image element after it has been added to the document, you'll have to have some way of referencing it.

A couple of ideas come to mind immediately:

1. Give the image a unique ID, and then use that:

   ```
   # First, change the html to include an id
   div.append('<img id="abcdef1234" class="prod48" src="' + url + '" />');

   #...
   # Later, grab the image by its id and change the source url
   var img = document.getElementById('abcdef1234');
   img.src = newUrl;
   ```
2. Alternately, construct the image dynamically the first time, and keep the element in a variable:

   ```
   # First, create an element, and hold it in a variable:
   var img = document.createElement('img');
   img.className = "prod48";
   img.src = url;
   # Now append it to the div:
   div.append(img);

   #...
   # Later, we still have that element, so we can just change the source URL:
   img.src = newUrl;
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But, how about replacing the already existing image. Kindly help me with that too. The issue with my case is append will go on appending the image, I need something of replace kind.

Comment: @NihalSharma do a .innerHTML() rather than .append() to replace

Comment: Awesome. Sometimes we miss on basic things. Thanks a lot. Add this in answer too.

Comment: @NihalSharma: I meant for you to change the way that you call `append`, so that you have a way to get the image later. The part after the `...` is the bit that replaces the image, by changing the `src` attribute.

Answer (score 2):

HTML :

```
<input type="text" id="url">
<div id="image_div">
    Will append image tag to this :     
</div>
```

JQUERY :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#image_div').html("<img src='' class='prod48'>");       //will replace image
    $('#url').change(function(){        
        $('.prod48').attr('src',$('#url').val());
    });
});
```

JSFiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nishantjani10/QMw85/)

Answer (score 0):

provide an id for the image and this code may help you..

```
$("img").attr("src", "/img/circleGraph/circle");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery you could do something like this:

```
var div = $('div');

div.append("<img src='"+url+"' />");

div.find("img").attr("src", newUrl);
```

Comment: whenever focusout is hit, the append will be called and it append the image everytime. I need to replace/update the existing image. So any if-else condition with the image will do the requirements.